# MySQL: Update rows change case

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with columns `Forename, Surname`.

These are all in uppercase but I want to re-format them for example:

```
Forename     |     Surname
--------------------------
John         |     Doe
```

rather than:

```
Forename     |     Surname
--------------------------
JOHN         |     DOE
```

Is it possible to do this on all rows via MySQL directly?

Comment: Set them all to lower then upper just the first character

Comment: Yeap, something like this: UPDATE t SET Forename = UPPER(SUBSTR(Forename,0,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTR(Forename,1))

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t
SET Forename= 
CONCAT((substr(Forename,1,1)), LOWER(substr(Forename,2)));
```

Same for the other

Comment: Isn't that what I have now?

Comment: @user4166144 Hold on my mistake.